# PHP GD & Imagick - Is there any way to measure image manipulation progress?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, imagick

Part of my app includes heavy use of image processing with features such as cropping, resizing, filters, brightness etc.

Is there anyway to measure the progress of GD and/or ImageMajick while an image manipulation is taking place?  I would like to be able to render a progress bar client side in the following way:-

1. Details about manipulation is collected client side and posted to server
2. On POST a procress bar is rendered client side starting at 0%.
3. the server runs GD or Imagick and processes the image during which it spits back progress  update data to the client.
4. The progress width of the progress bar is changed with javascript to reflect the returned progress data.
5. Eventually when the image manipulation progress is complete the new filename is sent back to the client and the src of an  tag is update.
6. The onload event is detected on the image and finally once it is rendered, the progress bar reaches 100% and the image is shown to the user.

If there is no possible way of retrieving progress data from either GD or Imagick could anyone suggest a way a 'faking it'?

I have considered rendering an empty progress bar before POST, animating it to 70% once the manipulation has taken place and the client receives back the ajax response.  Then finally animating to 100% once the new image has been fully loaded by detecting the onload event.

If this is my only option then so be it.  But it feels rather 'clunky' to me.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** - I have just seen that the command line version of ImageMajick has the option '-monitor' which returns the progress, so I may be able to knock something up by polling this every 50ms or so.  Is there anything similar for GD however as we use both GD/Imagick depending upon the manipulation required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, in case of using ImageMagick with exec you can add `-monitor` option, run command in background and send output to file

```
convert opts -monitor > /path/to/progress.txt 2>/path/to/progress.txt &
```

and then read that file periodically.

Also you can use `Imagick` extesnion wrapper and set callback function with
`Imagick::setProgressMonitor`. Combining with HTML5 Server-Sent Events it will be nice.

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$callback = function($offset, $span){

    echo "data: ".(100 * $offset) / $span."\n\n";
    flush();
    return true;
}

$imagick->setProgressMonitor($callback);
$imagick->waveImage(2, 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a collection of listeners and events to identify the source progress and then notify the client.

You can use [React](https://github.com/react-php/react) or pure lib event to make this progress async.